# Betti sum, cup-length, Lusternik-Schnirelmann category, and critical points

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to make some order in the notions of cup-length, sum of Betti numbers, LS category, critical points of functions.

Let $M$ be smooth closed compact manifold. We denote by Crit($M$) the minimal number of critical points of a smooth function on $M$, $BS(M)$ the sum of Betti numbers, CL(M) its cup-length, and $LS(M)$ its LS category.

What is known about the relations between these notions ?

It seems that $BS(M) \geq CL(M)$, and it was proved that $Crit(M) \geq LS(M) \geq CL(M)$. Am I mistaken here ?

Is something kown about the relation between $LS(M)$ and $BS(M)$ ?

Comment: At the very least, you have $BS(M) \geq Crit(M)$ when $M$ is a simply connected manifold of dimension at least 5, by handle cancellation techniques a la Smale's proof of the h-cobordism theorem.

Comment: Doesn't your example contradict Morse theorem ?

Comment: The comment describes how to construct a Morse function on $M$ with $BS(M)$ critical points.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the example. However, it still doesn't say what the relation between $LS(M)$ and $BS(M)$ is in general. Any idea ?

Comment: Combining that with the inequality $Crit(M) \geq LS(M)$ which is already in your post gives $BS(M) \geq LS(M)$. Observe that this inequality is not true for arbitrary manifolds: On page 354 of [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968905?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), it is explained that $LS(P) = 3$, where $P$ is the Poincare homology sphere, which has $BS(P) = 2$.

Comment: Ok, so to summarise, we have, in general: Crit$(M)$  $\geq LS(M) \geq CL(M)$, $BS(M) \geq CL(M)$, and Crit$(M) \geq BS(M)$, and that's all we can say. Am I right ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I might be wrong with the last inequality, which hold of course for Morse functions. Is there any example of a function with strictly less critical points that the sum of Betti numbers ?

Comment: Yes, many. See the book "Lusternik-Schnirelmann category" by Cornea-Lupton-Oprea-Tanre for a good discussion of this. It is a good reference for many related topics. In particular, Proposition 7.26 states that a closed connected manifold of dimension $n$ has $Crit(M) \leq n + 1$. So, for instance, every surface of genus $g$ admits a smooth function with three critical points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: See also the answers to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29434